# Googlesheets Filter or Query, to select values matching a Row by value and Column by IsBetween date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I'm attempting to make a general Profit and Loss report in GoogleSheets. The data I am using is in a Summary tab `Summary by Purchase Category`. Each row in Col A represent a category, and Col D:O represent months that expenses are stored at per category.

I'd like to have a To/From date filter, for various categories, such that I can get a sum of all data from the `Summary by Purchase Category` sheet such that it references all numbers within `Summary by Purchase Category!D:O` and between the date range of >=`P & L Standard'!B3` and <=`P & L Standard'!D3`, populate `P & L Standard'!D9` and beyond,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vz4ilugFb4uTn3o1HlMwqwNovCrWuEf2irxtJjaQB8U/edit?usp=sharing

An example here, With the date range in >=`P & L Standard'!B3` and <=`P & L Standard'!D3` of 2/1/23 & 4/1/23, such that a sum of the ranges is posted if `C=G` and if the `H:S` date range is between&equal-to B3 D3. The Green and Blue highlighted cells are summing numbers from placeholder data that I'm using to illustrate.

I am currently using placeholder data in `P & L Standard!G:S`, and I can get `=sum(filter(H2:S4,C11=G2:G4)` to sum everything across the data, but I cannot get the data between filters to work in tandem with the value=value filter. What must I do to get both filters working?

Comment: Please [edit] the question for clarity. Include a specific formula that isn't working and what it is supposed to do. Dates are numbers so can be compared using mathematical operators such as **`<>=`** etc. Consider including a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (more clarity, less content).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.